# Wordpress Woocommerce - Change the weight unit of measurement per product

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, units-of-measurement, measurement

I've tried to look everywhere for a plugin that will do what I'd like but I either missed it or there isn't one. What I need to do is change the unit of measurement per product in woocommerce:

eg

Product One weight - 1kg

Product Two weight (or volume) - 300mL

Product Three weight - 500g

The closest I've come to finding something that might be able to do this is [this WooThemes Plugin](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/measurement-price-calculator/).

Aside from that I'm stumped , any help is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I also would like know it... can someone help with this question??

Comment: What I ended up doing what having the weight field accept characters too so where it would say "1" (kg) , the kg on the frontend is hidden and instead I put "300mL" (kg) but all you see is the 300mL.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47508726/2149549

It explains how on Woocommerce -> Settings -> Products you can set the measurement units you want to use for your store.